# Can 2 segments have only 2 common points?

Tags: geometry

The question is in the title. I understand the case when there's only 1 common point, but 2 I have no idea how to prove. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Can $2$ lines have only $2$ common points?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb what does it have to do with lines? 1 segment can be the continuation of another segment, they don't have to intersect perpendicularly.

Comment: It seems like you're using some other definition of "segment" other than the common one.  With the accepted definition ThomasGrubb is right.  Some context would help everybody involved.

Comment: A-----B----C, BC is continuing AB, they have one common point B, is it possible to find another point behind B, B1? So there are 2 common points B and B1? Or is it not possible because real numbers are uncountable?

Comment: If you mean line segment, then the number of common points they can share is $0,1$ or infinitely many. It is not possible to meet at exactly $2$ points.

Comment: @Haran this is what I thought, I just needed reassurance. But how do you formally write out the proof for this?

Comment: Do you know how to write the equation of a line?

Comment: Suppose that both $p_1$ and $p_2$ were points on both line segments $L_1$ and $L_2$.  It follows from definition of line segments (*using a suitable definition of line segment*) that all points between $p_1$ and $p_2$ are also points on $L_1$ as well as on $L_2$.  This assumes of course we are working with Euclidean Geometry.  You can of course have two line segments intersect at exactly two points in spherical geometry or others, e.g. the equator meets the prime meridian exactly twice.

Comment: @JMoravitz but this book I'm reading is for 6th grade, I don't know if it's possible to use uncountability for this

Comment: That would actually be better. This question is kind of the consequence of postulates

Comment: I never mentioned countability or uncountability, but you should regardless of level have a sufficiently rigorous definition for line segments, the definition I would propose is that a line segment $L$ with endpoints $a,b$ is the set $\{at+(1-t)b~:~t\in[0,1]\}$.  Reworded, it is the set of all points directly between $a$ and $b$.  Further you should be aware that the real numbers and/or rational numbers are dense, that there is always something between such as how $a<b\implies a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$.  Similarly so for tuples in $\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R^3,\Bbb Q^2,\dots$

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks

Comment: On a projective line you can have two segments having exactly two points in common.

Comment: I think the comments here demonstrate that you need to give a bit more detail about the question - it seems that you are thinking about segments in a plane, or perhaps in three dimensional (Euclidean) space. But mathematicians have found a use for many different kinds of geometry in which "segment" makes sense. As for the elementary case, if two segments share two points, what about the midpoint of those - does it belong to both? That deals with the elementary part of your question without going into infinities.